# Using a Python dictionary with multiple values, how can you output the data in a table with Jinja's for loops?

Tags: python, django, loops, dictionary, jinja2

I am using Django to make an API request for current standings in a league table. I would like to display this data as a table in HTML. Here is the code I am using in views.py to make the Python dictionary.

```
# Receive the json response
    response = json.loads(connection.getresponse().read().decode())
# Declare the dict to use
    current_table = {"position": [], "team":[], "points":[]}
    
# Loop over 20 times as there are 20 teams in the league
    for x in range(20):
        team = response["standings"][0]["table"][x]["team"]["name"]
        points = response["standings"][0]["table"][x]["points"]
        current_table["position"].append(x + 1)
        current_table["team"].append(team)
        current_table["points"].append(points)
    return render(request, "predict/index.html", {
        "table": current_table, 
    })
```

The raw output of the dict in the terminal and with {{ table }} using jinja is

```
{'position': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20], 'team': ['Manchester City FC', 'Manchester United FC', 'Liverpool FC', 'Chelsea FC', 'Leicester City FC', 'West Ham United FC', 'Tottenham Hotspur FC', 'Arsenal FC', 
'Leeds United FC', 'Everton FC', 'Aston Villa FC', 'Newcastle United FC', 'Wolverhampton Wanderers FC', 'Crystal Palace FC', 'Southampton FC', 'Brighton & Hove Albion FC', 'Burnley FC', 'Fulham FC', 'West Bromwich Albion FC', 'Sheffield United FC'], 'points': [86, 74, 69, 67, 66, 65, 62, 61, 59, 59, 55, 45, 45, 44, 43, 41, 39, 28, 26, 23]}
```

I feel like there should be an elegant way of doing this, as the data is all there. Ideally, I would like to use something along the lines of this in index.html.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Position</th>
        <th>Team</th>
        <th>Points</th>
    </tr>
    {% for x in table %}
    <tr>
       <td>{{ x.position }}</td>
       <td>{{ x.team }}</td>
       <td>{{ x.points }}</td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
```

This however, does not work, and it seems to think that there are only 3 cylces to go through (as the dict has 3 keys?). I think I may have to rethink the way I have made the dict in Python, as typically there isn't meant to be multiple keys per one value? I have tried using .items() in Jinja, but it doesn't seem to like the brackets which suggests there may be something wrong with the dict output?

I guess my problem could be solved with an SQL table or Django models, but as I'm using an API I don't know if it is a good idea for tables to be continuously updating?

My main question is, I found a way for the data to be displayed, but only by accessing one column at a time. Is there a way to merge these 3 loops in jinja into one so that the data doesn't get caught in each other's cycles?

```
{% for x in table.position %}
{% for y in table.team %}
{% for z in table.points %}
<tr>
    <td>{{ x }}</td>
    <td>{{ y }}</td>
    <td>{{ z }}</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

This is my first post on here, please let me know if I need to provide any other info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay - an easier data structure to work with would be something like this:

```py
teams = [
  {
    "position" : 1,
    "name" : "Manchester City FC",
    "points" : 86
  },
  {
    "position" : 2,
    "name" : "Manchester United FC",
    "points" : 74
  },
  ...
]
```

Then, in your template, you can do:

```html
...
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th> Position </th>
      <th> Team </th>
      <th> Points </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    {% for team in teams %}
    <tr>
      <td> {{ team.position }} </td>
      <td> {{ team.name }} </td>
      <td> {{ team.points }} </td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
  </tbody>
</table>
```

So let's change the way we interact with the api like so:

```py
# Receive the json response:
response = json.loads(connection.getresponse().read().decode())

# initialize an empty list (not a dictionary):
teams = []
    
# Loop over 20 times as there are 20 teams in the league
for x in range(20):

    # initialize an empty team dictionary:
    team = {}

    # set position:
    team["position"] = x + 1

    # set name:
    team["name"] = response["standings"][0]["table"][x]["team"]["name"]
    
    # set points:
    team["points"] = response["standings"][0]["table"][x]["points"]

    # finally, append the team dictionary to the teams list:
    teams.append(team)
```